# Arithmetic in tikz coordinates (parentheses)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to use parentheses in coordinate calculation in tikz.
There should be a simple way, but I couldn't find it.
For example,

```
\def\x{10};
\draw (0,0) -- (1+1/\x,0);
```

this works fine. But,

```
\def\x{10};
\draw (0,0) -- (1+1/{\x+1},0);
```

this doesn't work. Other parentheses didn't work either. What is the expression for parentheses?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If your expression contains parentheses or commas, you may use `{}` around the whole expression:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\x{10};
  \draw (0,0) -- (1+1/\x,0);
  \draw (0,0) -- ({1+1/(\x+1)},0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why "you may" ? After experimenting with some Tikz calculation, I'd rather say "you must".

Comment: @kebs Another solution: you may use `\pgfmathsetmacro\mytemp{1+1/(\x+1)}; \draw (0,0) -- (\mytemp,0);`. Or use a `let` operation...