# Arithmetic inside tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I'm having difficulty performing arithmetic inside `tikz`.

I've written:

```
  \foreach \s in {6,...,8}
  {  
  \node[draw,red,circle] at (0:(\s-2)cm) {$\s$};
  }
```

Somehow the arithmetic `(\s-2)` is not working, I think its the `cm` that's causing the issue but I need the measurement in `cm`.

Also if I write:

```
  \node[draw,red,circle] at (0:\s cm) {$(\s-2)$};
```

the arithmetic does not work and LaTeX just merrily shows `(6-2) (7-2)` etc...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet compilable ...

Comment: Here, you must use braces around your formula (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218542/14500) and multiply by `1cm`:  `(0:{(\s-2)*1cm}) `.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unit of tikz is the `cm`, so it is useless to specify it. As for the calculations, they are done here without the need for brackets.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,fadings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,blue,circle] at(0:2cm){4};
\node[draw,blue,circle] at(0:3){5};
\node[draw,blue,circle] at(0:4cm){6};
 \foreach \s in {6,...,8}
  {  
  \node[fill=red,circle,opacity=.5] at (0:\s-2) {$\s$};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you still want to specify the unit, it is necessary to do it after each of the Numbers: `(0:\s cm-2cm) {$\s$};`

Or to do as indicated by @PaulGaborit by factoring the unit: `(0:{(\s-2)*1cm})`

[image: calculs]

Answer (score 6):

You can't use arithmetic as you shown directly (in the description of a node or if you explicitly put a unit of measure after it).

Just use `evaluate` option of the `\foreach` macro.

Here I create a new variable `\mys` which assumes the value `\s-2`.

In my first `tikzpicture`, `\mys` is used for positioning; in the second, for description:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach[evaluate=\s as \mys using int(\s-2)] \s in {6,...,8}
  {  
  \node[draw,red,circle] at (0:\mys cm) {$\s$};
  }
 \end{tikzpicture}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach[evaluate=\s as \mys using int(\s-2)] \s in {6,...,8}
  {  
  \node[draw,red,circle] at (0:\s cm) {$\mys$};
  }
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]