# TikZ ! Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hi all, here is a (hopefully not oversimplified) MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\A{{3/(2*6)}}
\def\B{{sqrt(5-\A)}}

\filldraw (\A,\B) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm getting the error message

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
            {
l.11 \filldraw ({\A,\B})
               circle (1pt);
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here? How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arithmetic in tikz coordinates (parentheses)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218541/arithmetic-in-tikz-coordinates-parentheses)

Comment: BTW, welcome to this site.

Comment: @Werner No, it is not a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to fix this is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathsetmacro\A{3/(2*6)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\B{sqrt(5-\A)}

\filldraw (\A,\B) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you insist on `\def`s, set the braces right:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\A{3/(2*6)}
\def\B{sqrt(5-\A)}

\filldraw ({\A},{\B}) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your second solution works! Didn't try the first one --  is `pgfmathsetmacro` recommended over `def`?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform The general rule is that `\def` should used sparsely. However, the reason is that it overwrites macros without warning (while `\newcommand` would issue an error message). This objection applies to `\pgfmathsetmacro`, too, but this one at least parses the expression. In more complex examples this may save some time. The real advantages include the ability to, say, local switch on `fpu`, which is not needed in this cooked down example. In any case, the braces in your `\def`s are not set appropriately.